# Using hazArg() and rnorm together within a function in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to make it so that if the user fails to supply an input (i.e. meanANDsd()) the default is to use rnorm() to generate 20 random normal numbers, and return the standard deviation only.
It works if there is an x, but say there's no default when there's no x.
This is the code I have so far, I'm new so I'm not really sure what I'm doing, especially with the else code.

```
meanAndsd <- function(x){ 
  if(hasArg("x")){
    av <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
    sdev <- sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)
    size <- length(na.omit(x))
    c(mean=av, sd = sdev, size = size)
  }
  else { 
    sd(rnorm=20)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simplified the code and added argument to `rnorm()`

```
meanAndsd <- function(x){ 
  if(hasArg("x")){
    c(mean=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 
      sd = sd(x, na.rm=TRUE), 
      size = length(na.omit(x)))
  }
  else { 
    sd(rnorm(20))
  }
}
```